# An upper bound for $\sum_{n,m} \left(|a_n\phi_n|^2+|a_m\phi_m|^2\right) \left|K_{n-m}\right|$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let us consider $a_n, \phi_n, K_{n}$ complex sequences. Let
$$\sum_{n,m} \left(|a_n\phi_n|^2+|a_m\phi_m|^2\right) \left|K_{n-m}\right|$$
where $\left|K_{n}\right|\leq \gamma$ and $\gamma>0$. Can we infer that
$$\sum_{n,m} \left(|a_n\phi_n|^2+|a_m\phi_m|^2\right) \left|K_{n-m}\right|\leq C(\gamma) \sum_n |a_n\phi_n|^2$$
where $C$ is a constant that depends by $\gamma$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are the sums finite or infinite ?

Comment: @jibounet, it's infinite.

Comment: Then I believe this is not possible. Let : $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \; K_{n}=\phi_{n}=1$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \; a_{n} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$. It follows that :

$$ \sum_{n,m \in \mathbb{Z}} \big\( \vert a_{n}\phi_{n} \vert^{2} + \vert a_{m}\phi_{m} \vert^{2} \big) \vert K_{n-m} \vert = \sum_{n,m \in \mathbb{Z}} \Big( \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{m^{2}} \Big) = +\infty. $$

Therefore, it cannot be bounded by $1 \times \displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n^{2}} < +\infty$.

Comment: Edit: $a_{n}$ is obviously not defined for $n=0$. Letting $a_{0}=0$ and $a_{n} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ast}$ is more correct.